# SQL / PHP converting a string to float or int

Tags: php, sql, floating-point, int

I have this sql query..

```
select i.invoiceid as transactionid, i.date, i.total, 
'invoice' as transaction_type
from invoice
```

and I ran it in php and echo out the total in a foreach loop like so....

```
echo gettype($row['total']) . "<br/>";
```

and all the totals returned `string`

how would I convert the i.total in my sql query to int or float?

i've tried

`convert(int, i.total)`

and that didnt work :(

Answer (score 3):

**php handles everything (that's not an array/dictionary) as a string** unless you specifically tell it not to with something like `(int)$row['total']`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
select i.invoiceid as transactionid, i.date, CAST(i.total as int) as total, 
'invoice' as transaction_type
from invoice
```

Comment: This gives me an SQL Error(1064)